# Treinando ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Galera,

Estou precisando estudar PL/SQL mas meu notebook não está suportando o Oracle Database Express.
Existe alguma ferramenta mais leve ou algum site que eu consiga treinar?

Obrigado!

Comment: O que aconteceu pra você constatar que seu notebook **não suporta** o Oracle Database?

Comment: 8Ele começou a travar demais. O uso da CPU estava chegando a 100% ao executar o Oracle.
Ele tem 4GB de Ram e 1T de HD. Processador i3.

Comment: se for coisas básicas, pode usar o [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o Oracle LiveSQL direto do browser para aprender:

https://livesql.oracle.com/

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com um problema semelhante, no site da Oracle você encontra o Oracle Database Express Edition 11G de 317MB, super leve e roda muito bem!

Comment: Muito obrigado!